# Windows mongodb server bind_ip configuration

Tags: windows, mongodb

I would like to ask help on the allowing remote connections from my Mongodb server.

I have here my configuration but not working, i see "connect failed" on my remote machine.

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

Did I made a mistake?

Comment: Remove `--bin_ip 0.0.0.0` and let mongod run free. Can you connect locally (running mongo on the same host)? You probably have Windows firewall running on that host. Open tcp port 27017. Ask on [SF] for details.

Comment: Okay got it. the firewall blocked the port. So i open the port 27017 http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7

Comment: guys, I'm being pedantic here, but it's `bind_ip`, not `bin_ip`. This could irritate new users because you both use the string as if it were correct.

Comment: thanks, just miswritten :)

Answer (score 2):

your command should be :

C:\mongodb\bin\mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

the IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IP of the Remote Machine (where mongo DB is there)