# Unable to connect to MongDB through IP address

Tags: mongodb

I have installed MongoDb 4.0 on Windows 10. MongoDB currently runs on 'localhost'. I am able to connect to MongoDB by using 'mongodb://localhost:27017' in my nodeJS. However, I have a need to access this MondoDB instance through IP address. So, if I access MondoDB using mongodb://193.168.16.1:27017, then I am not able to connect to it. I tried to connect  through MongoDB atlas, but I am having the same problem.

I have gone through the following threads on stackoverflow before posting it here.

[Bind MongoDB to IP address when running as Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876326/bind-mongodb-to-ip-address-when-running-as-service)

[Windows mongodb server bind_ip configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615230/windows-mongodb-server-bind-ip-configuration)

I have already tried to change the bindIp in mongod.cfg with the following values, with no success. I restarted 'MongoDB server' service after making these changes.I have also enabled all connections on port 27017 in windows firewall

> bindIpAll: true #no success
>   bindIp: 127.0.0.1,193.168.16.1  #no  success
>   bindIp: 193.168.16.1  #no success
>   bindIp: 0.0.0.0  #no  success

Comment: use the same port on accessing, you are using 27101 but it's 27017

Comment: The port name is 27017 in the firewall configuration. I had typed it wrongly in the question. I have corrected it.

Comment: ok what is your system ipv4 address

Comment: It is given in the question. (193.168.16.1).

Comment: How you are passing database name? Could you please share config file full code?

Comment: I am using this one  mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db_test and perfectly working with my local IP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start your mongodb server something like this,

```
mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 -v
```

And now you will be able to connect to mongodb using ipAddress.

Comment: It's not the recommended way to do that

Comment: Than you can bind your own ip in place of 0.0.0.0 Like,
    `mongod --bind_ip 193.168.16.1 -v`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please kill MongoDB and run this:

```
mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 -v
```

Then as you want to connect through IP so run this command:

```
mongo --host 193.168.16.1 --verbose
```

Hope this will solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

None of the above suggestions worked for me. One of the combinations that worked for me is as follows

```
 bindIp: 0.0.0.0,192.168.16.1
```

I am not sure why other combinations are not working. It could possibly be due to some issue with the MogoDb service, because I had to restart the service twice to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was not reading the config file until I removed the service and created it again specifying the configuration file path.

`mongod --remove`

`"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg" --service`

I had to comment `#mp:` at the end of the configuration file before I could run the service.

Answer (score 0):

After change bindIp variable to your ip (192.168.16.1) in \Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg you should run `net stop mongodb` in cmd and `net start mongodb`(to restart mongod server).